# F# Powerset Function

Tags: recursion, f#, powerset

The function below returns the powerset of a set (list).

```
let rec powerset = function
  | [] -> [[]]
  | x::xs -> List.collect (fun sub -> [sub; x::sub]) (powerset xs)
```

I don't understand why exactly it works. I understand recursion. I also understand how List.collect works. I know that recursion will continue until an instance of powerset returns [[]]. However, I try to trace the returned values after that point and I never obtain the complete power set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm for calculating power set goes like this:

Let's call the original set (aka "input") `A`. And let's pick out an item from that set, call it `x`. Now, powerset of `A` (call it `P(A)`) is a set of all subsets of `A`. We can think of all subsets of `A` as consisting of two groups: subsets that include `x` and those that don't include `x`. It's easy to see that subsets that don't include `x` are all possible subsets of `A - x` (`A` with `x` excluded):

```
  all subsets of A that don't include x = P(A-x)
```

How do we get all subsets of `A` that *do* include `x`? By taking all those that don't include `x` and sticking `x` into each one!

```
  all subsets of A that include x = { for each S in P(A-x) : S+x }
```

Now we just need to combine the two, and we get ourselves `P(A)`:

```
  P(A) = P(A-x) + { for each S in P(A-x) : S+x }
```

This is what the last line in your code example does: it calculates `P(A-x)` by calling `powerset xs`, and then for each of those subsets, sticks an `x` onto it, and also includes the subset itself.

Comment: Great explanation! Now I understand the reason behind it. Thanks a lot.